# Getting error in XSLT transformation stylesheet

Tags: xslt

I have transformation which is giving me error regarding style sheet. Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>M-ID-3543</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2013-10-15T11:44:14.0Z</CreDtTm>
            <InitgPty>
                <Id>
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>JP Morgan</Id>
                            <SchmeNm>
                                <Cd>BANK</Cd>
                            </SchmeNm>
                        </Othr>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlMsgId>00014354</OrgnlMsgId>
            <OrgnlMsgNmId>pain.001</OrgnlMsgNmId>
            <OrgnlNbOfTxs>1</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
            <OrgnlCtrlSum>2414034.080</OrgnlCtrlSum>
            <GrpSts>ACSP</GrpSts>
            <NbOfTxsPerSts>
                <DtldNbOfTxs>1</DtldNbOfTxs>
                <DtldSts>ACSP</DtldSts>
                <DtldCtrlSum>2414034.080</DtldCtrlSum>
            </NbOfTxsPerSts>
            <NbOfTxsPerSts>
                <DtldNbOfTxs>0</DtldNbOfTxs>
                <DtldSts>RJCT</DtldSts>
                <DtldCtrlSum>0.000</DtldCtrlSum>
            </NbOfTxsPerSts>
        </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
        <OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlPmtInfId>AP0000000441</OrgnlPmtInfId>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>AP0000000441</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <TxSts>ACSP</TxSts>
                <AcctSvcrRef>4700000288JO0000</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="USD">2414034.08</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdExctnDt>2013-10-16</ReqdExctnDt>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
        </OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
    </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

And my XSLT is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:ons="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="ons:CstmrPmtStsRpt">
        <PAYMENT_ACKNOWLEDGE>
            <FieldTypes>
                <PMT_ACK_HEADER class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <ACK_FILE_STATUS type="CHAR"/>
                    <BANK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <BANK_SEND_DTTM type="DATETIME"/>
                    <FORMAT_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <OUTPUT_TYPE type="CHAR"/>
                    <PMT_FILE_PATH type="CHAR"/>
                    <FILENAME type="CHAR"/>
                    <CREATE_DTTM type="DATETIME"/>
                    <CREATED_BY_USER type="CHAR"/>
                    <PMT_CRYPTO_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <PUBNODE type="CHAR"/>
                    <MSGNAME type="CHAR"/>
                    <APMSGVER type="CHAR"/>
                    <CHNLNAME type="CHAR"/>
                    <PUBID type="NUMBER"/>
                    <EVENT_TRACKING_ID type="NUMBER"/>
                    <BANK_SETID type="CHAR"/>
                    <BANK_CD type="CHAR"/>
                    <BANK_ID_QUAL type="CHAR"/>
                    <BNK_ID_NBR type="CHAR"/>
                    <DFI_ID_NUM type="CHAR"/>
                    <DFI_ID_QUAL type="CHAR"/>
                    <BIC_ID type="CHAR" />
                </PMT_ACK_HEADER>
                <PMT_ACK_ERR class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <PYMNT_REF_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <SEQ_NUM type="NUMBER"/>
                    <ERROR_CODE type="CHAR"/>
                    <ERROR_MESSAGE type="CHAR"/>
                </PMT_ACK_ERR>
                <PMT_FILE_ACK class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <HEADER_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS type="CHAR"/>
                    <NUM_PMTS_ACCEPTED type="NUMBER"/>
                    <NUM_PMTS_IN_ERROR type="NUMBER"/>
                    <ORIG_MSG_NAME type="CHAR"/>
                    <ORIG_NUM_TRAN type="NUMBER"/>
                    <ORIG_CTRL_SUM type="NUMBER"/>
                </PMT_FILE_ACK>
                <PMT_ACK class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <PYMNT_REF_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <PMT_STATUS type="CHAR"/>
                    <BANK_REF_ID type="CHAR"/>
                </PMT_ACK>
                <PMT_FILE_ERR class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <HEADER_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <SEQ_NUM type="NUMBER"/>
                    <ERROR_CODE type="CHAR"/>
                    <ERROR_MESSAGE type="CHAR"/>
                </PMT_FILE_ERR>
                <PSCAMA class="R">
                    <LANGUAGE_CD type="CHAR"/>
                    <AUDIT_ACTN type="CHAR"/>
                    <BASE_LANGUAGE_CD type="CHAR"/>
                    <MSG_SEQ_FLG type="CHAR"/>
                    <PROCESS_INSTANCE type="NUMBER"/>
                    <PUBLISH_RULE_ID type="CHAR"/>
                    <MSGNODENAME type="CHAR"/>
                </PSCAMA>
            </FieldTypes>
            <MsgData>
                <Transaction>
                    <PMT_ACK_HEADER class="R">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:GrpHdr"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:OrgnlGrpInfAndSts"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:TxInfAndSts"/>
                    </PMT_ACK_HEADER>
                    <PSCAMA class="R">
                        <LANGUAGE_CD>ENG</LANGUAGE_CD>
                        <AUDIT_ACTN/>
                        <BASE_LANGUAGE_CD>ENG</BASE_LANGUAGE_CD>
                        <MSG_SEQ_FLG/>
                        <PROCESS_INSTANCE>0</PROCESS_INSTANCE>
                        <PUBLISH_RULE_ID/>
                        <MSGNODENAME/>
                    </PSCAMA>
                </Transaction>
            </MsgData>
        </PAYMENT_ACKNOWLEDGE>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ons:GrpHdr">
        <PMT_ACK_HEADER class="R">
            <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
            <ACK_FILE_STATUS IsChanged="Y">P</ACK_FILE_STATUS>
            <BANK_FILE_ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:MsgId"/>
            </BANK_FILE_ID>
            <BANK_SEND_DTTM>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:CreDtTm"/>
            </BANK_SEND_DTTM>
            <FORMAT_ID/>
            <OUTPUT_TYPE/>
            <PMT_FILE_PATH/>
            <FILENAME/>
            <CREATE_DTTM/>
            <CREATED_BY_USER/>
            <PMT_CRYPTO_ID/>
            <PUBNODE/>
            <MSGNAME/>
            <APMSGVER/>
            <CHNLNAME/>
            <PUBID>0</PUBID>
            <EVENT_TRACKING_ID>0</EVENT_TRACKING_ID>
            <BANK_SETID/>
            <BANK_CD/>
            <BANK_ID_QUAL/>
            <BNK_ID_NBR/>
            <DFI_ID_NUM/>
            <DFI_ID_QUAL/>
            <BIC_ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:BIC"/>
            </BIC_ID>
        </PMT_ACK_HEADER>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ons:OrgnlGrpInfAndSts">
        <PMT_FILE_ACK class="R">
            <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
            <HEADER_ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:OrgnlMsgId"/>
            </HEADER_ID>
            <xsl:variable name="group_status" select="ons:GrpSts"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='ACSP'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>A</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='ACSC'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>A</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='ACCP'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>A</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='PART'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>W</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='RJCT'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>E</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='RCVD'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>R</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='PDNG'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>R</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$group_status='ACTC'">
                    <FILE_ACK_STATUS>R</FILE_ACK_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <NUM_PMTS_ACCEPTED/>
            <NUM_PMTS_IN_ERROR/>
            <ORIG_MSG_NAME>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="OrgnlMsgNmId"/>
            </ORIG_MSG_NAME>
            <ORIG_NUM_TRAN>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="OrgnlNbOfTxs"/>
            </ORIG_NUM_TRAN>
            <ORIG_CTRL_SUM>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="OrgnlCtrlSum"/>
            </ORIG_CTRL_SUM>
            <xsl:variable name="error_code" select="ons:Rsn"/>
            <xsl:if test='string-length($error_code) >
                0'>
                <PMT_FILE_ERR class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
                    <HEADER_ID>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:OrgnlMsgId"/>
                    </HEADER_ID>
                    <SEQ_NUM>1</SEQ_NUM>
                    <ERROR_CODE>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:Rsn"/>
                    </ERROR_CODE>
                    <xsl:call-template name="StatusReasonMsg">
                        <xsl:with-param name="error_code">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:Rsn"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </PMT_FILE_ERR>
            </xsl:if >
        </PMT_FILE_ACK>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ons:TxInfAndSts">
        <PMT_ACK class="R">
            <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
            <PYMNT_REF_ID>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
            </PYMNT_REF_ID>
            <xsl:variable name="tx_status" select="ons:TxSts"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='ACCP'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>P</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='ACSC'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>P</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='ACSP'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>R</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='ACTC'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>R</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='PDNG'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>R</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$tx_status='RJCT'">
                    <PMT_STATUS>E</PMT_STATUS>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <BANK_REF_ID></BANK_REF_ID>
            <xsl:variable name="error_code" select="Rsn"/>
            <xsl:if test='string-length($error_code) >
                0'>
                <PMT_ACK_ERR class="R">
                    <PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
                    <PYMNT_REF_ID>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:PmtId/EndToEndId"/>
                    </PYMNT_REF_ID>
                    <SEQ_NUM>1</SEQ_NUM>
                    <ERROR_CODE>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:Rsn"/>
                    </ERROR_CODE>
                    <xsl:call-template name="StatusReasonMsg">
                        <xsl:with-param name="error_code">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ons:Rsn"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </PMT_ACK_ERR>
            </xsl:if >
        </PMT_ACK>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="StatusReasonMsg">
        <xsl:param name="error_code"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AC01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Format of the account number specified is not correct.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AC04'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Account number specified has been closed on the Receivers books.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AC06'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Account specified is blocked, prohibiting posting of transactions against it.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AG01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Transaction forbidden on this type of account.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AG02'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Bank Operation code specified in the transaction message is not valid for Receiver.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specified transaction message amount is equal to zero.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM02'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specified transaction message amount is greater than allowed maximum.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM03'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specified transaction message amount is in an non processable currency outside of existing agreement.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM04'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Amount of funds available to cover specified transaction message amount is insufficient.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM05'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>This transaction message appears to have been duplicated.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM06'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specified transaction amount is less than agreed minimum.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM07'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Amount specified in transaction message has been blocked by regulatory authorities.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM09'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Amount received is not the amount agreed or expected.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='AM10'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Sum of instructed amounts does not equal the control sum.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='BE01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specification of creditor is not consistent with associated account number.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='BE04'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Specification of creditors address, which is required for payment, is missing/not correct.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='BE05'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Party who initiated the transaction message is not recognised by the end customer.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='DT01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Invalid date (e.g. wrong settlement date).</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='ED01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Correspond bank not possible.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='ED03'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Balance of payments complementary info is requested.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='ED05'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Settlement of the transaction has failed.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MS01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Reason has not been specified due to sensitivities.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Mandate is cancelled or invalid.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD02'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Mandate related information data required by the scheme is missing.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD03'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>File format incomplete or invalid.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD04'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>File format incorrect in terms of grouping indicator.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD06'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Return of funds requested by end customer.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MD07'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>End customer is deceased.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='MS02'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Reason has not been specified by end customer.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='NARR'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Reason is provided as narrative information in the additional reason information.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='RC01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Bank identifier code specified in the message has an incorrect format.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='RF01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Transaction reference is not unique within the message.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$error_code='TM01'">
                <ERROR_MESSAGE>Associated transaction message was received after agreed processing cut-off time.</ERROR_MESSAGE>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although I have provided everything in stylesheet

Comment: Show the error message; very few of us are telepathic. ;-) Also, show as much as the stylesheet as possible. And show us how you are running the stylesheet (i.e., are you using xsltproc, SAXON 5, etc.)?

Comment: Let me repeat what Dave Jarvis says. If you get an error, tell us what the error is. You might not understand the error message (perhaps it uses technical terms you don't yet understand), but the chances are that experienced users will recognize it and be able to explain it. Looking at the error message is the first step in diagnosing a problem, so you really can't expect anyone to tackle this question without seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your namespaces declared wrong in the XSLT.

Change this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:ons="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" 
version="1.0">
```

To this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ons="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" 
version="1.0">
```